# How to use "for the sake of"

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

What option is better to use?

1. Event for the event's sake
2. Event for the sake of the event

Comment: Can you give a more realistic example?  Can you replace the word "event" with what you actually want to say?

Comment: Actually, this is what I want to say)) I want to describe a situation when companies hold marketing activities (events, special offers. etc.) just to keep them in a marketing plan. These activities have no practical purpose, so they are held just for the sake of the event or special offer.

Comment: Ah, you are probably basing this of the idiom "art for art's sake" - I don't think you can change that to "event". I think you'd need to write out the situation and context in more detail.

Comment: I based on the following: 
sake noun (REASON) 
for the sake of something/for something's sake 
because of, or for the purpose of something.
 
Source: Cambridge Dictionary

Comment: _Events for their own sake_ would sound better.

Comment: Maybe I can say "Event for the sake of activity?"

Answer (score 1):

Except for the idiom "art for art's sake", it is unusual to say that the purpose of something is the thing itself.

A marketing event might be pointless, but it is odd to say "The purpose of holding the marketing event was holding the marketing event".  Therefore it sounds strange to say "This was an event for the event's sake."

I guess you are trying to criticise an event as being unnecessary.  You should probably think about what the purpose of the event really is:

> This event is being held just for the sake of spending the marketing department's budget. It won't help sell our product.

Comment: "X for X's sake" is quite common when X is singular and an abstract uncountable noun: Googling shows examples with music for music's sake, fun for fun's sake, sport for sport's sake, and probably other terms. But doing it with a plural or a noun that requires an article is more complex.